# How to draw a smooth path across points around a circle

Tags: javascript, canvas, bezier, linegraph

This might be a math question... I have a set of points on a circular axis. Let's call the circle x and the radius of the points y. The problem is twofold:

1. I want a smooth line across all points. Let's assume it's a normal x/y graph: I know the exact coordinates. Now how do I create a smooth path between all those points?
2. It's not a normal x/y graph. It's an a/r graph (angle/radius). The solution from 1. could be applied, I guess, but where do I draw that line? (I'm not sure it being an a/r graph makes it any more difficult.)

(I want to create this on a `<canvas>` with Javascript. I've set up something for the eager: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/5LfdP/1/)

What I'm looking for is

[image: smooth line graph]

wrapped around a circle with the ends meeting (so 0% = 350 and 100% = 350).

It feels like a cubic bezier is necessary to create the smooth paths between points, but that's all I got. [This is the bezier function I usually use.](https://gist.github.com/rudiedirkx/5266253/raw/87e4f7cd4a569b538c13b36d03d6ed8ed5fcc570/bezier.js)

Am I making any sense? I can't find a better picture. (Probably because I've no idea what it's called.)

**Edit 1:** My attempt at a drawing of how it would look: http://www.sketchtoy.com/26800595 (forget the animation, that's just how sketchtoy works)

**Edit 2:** I've updated my [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/5LfdP/2/show/) using quadraticCurveTo(), but that's not good enough. I need bezier curves and twice as much to make the curve go THROUGH the points. Like in [About Spline Interpolation](http://scaledinnovation.com/analytics/splines/aboutSplines.html) but hopefully simpler.

Comment: 350... did you mean 360, as in degrees?

Comment: No I meant the 350 from the graph. Could be any Y value. Just that the curve closes around a circle.

Comment: so 0% - 100% is the X axis that wraps around the circle to join ends, and the y axis is the length of the "cylinder"? So you're really looking for a 3D chart? Will the cylinder be transparent, or will it be opaque (and if so how will the user rotate it to see all the curve)?

Comment: @Rudie: Would it be possible to create an image mock-up of how you need it to appear on the screen after it's been "wrapped around a circle"? Is the end result a 2D shape, or a 3D shape (a cylinder possibly)? Either way, depending on the shape, you might be able to create a 2D graph and texture-map it onto the shape, to simplify things a little.

Comment: It's very 2D. It's one big curve (consisting of a lot of small curves) around a circle. I've added a link in the body.

Comment: @Rudie: I'm guessing that drawing bezier curves for points on a linear graph is no different than drawing bezier curves for points from a circular axis that have been mapped to x,y coordinates (around the origin). I don't think the orientation of the points matters. Let's say you took the points of a linear graph, rotated them around the center 45 degrees, and then drew the bezier curves. I think the end result would be exactly the same as if you drew the bezier curves and then rotated the rendered curves around the center 45 degrees.

Comment: @Rudie: Changed my answer to a comment, and added one of your comments to the question. The relevant canvas path functions: [quadraticCurveTo()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_quadraticcurveto.asp), [bezierCurveTo()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beziercurveto.asp). LukeH mentioned that the [About Spline Interpolation](http://scaledinnovation.com/analytics/splines/aboutSplines.html) site you found may be more or less the simplest option.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the function expression for your graph, you can simply plot it turning your coordinates into polar coordinates with a circular offset. Treating 'x' as your angle (with min_x being angle "0" and max_x being angle "360", or for computers, "2π"), using these mappings:

```
φ (the angle) = map x from interval (min_x,max_x) to interval (0,2π);
a (the amplitude) = map y from (min_y,max_y) to (0, max_distance);
```

You can then the x/y coordinates you want your function plotted is:

```
nx = a * cos(φ);
ny = a * sin(φ);
```

And for graph plotting, I can strongly recommend building a lookup table for your values, so you can bypass having to constantly compute the original x/y values. If you don't have a function, but just a series of points, then you effectively already have this LUT.

After transforming your LUT x/y coordinates, drawing a nice looking curve through each of them is probably a job for a Catmull-Rom spline, not a Bezier, since Catmull-Rom splines go through each point you use, whereas Bezier curves don't, they skirt around every point except the start and end point, so they're unsuited for what you want to do.

Comment: I've no idea what that means... Do I have a function expression? I only have a fixed set of X and Y values. Don't I need bezier curves? How would I circularly offset those? I no get it!

Comment: I edited the answer to better reflect what applies in your case.